# Script that takes a search string, searches for folders containing the string and moves them to a folder with the same name as the string

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, command-line

Basically what I want to do is compact

```
mkdir STRING
mv 00/*[sS][tT][rR][iI][nN][gG]* STRING
```

into a single command like **do-this STRING** having the results be the same. The string could contain some special characters like spaces.

I realize that omitting the first line will often do the same thing, but it doesn't appear to do so consistently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a `bash` function to do it:

```
function doThis {
    mkdir "$1"
    find 00 -maxdepth 1 -iname "*$1*" -exec mv {} "$1" \;
}
```

Then call it like so:

```
doThis STRING
```

Comment: Or `-exec mv -t "$1" \+` if your `find` supports this extension.